# Android - custom quick search box

Tags: android, customization, quick-search

If you using Twitter for Android you can see that clicking on phone's hard search button brings fully customized quick search-like control. Now I'm not saying that it IS stock Android customized quick search but how would one build something like that? 
I want quick search box behavior but I also want add some additional selectors (think Firefox search where on the left there's a dropdown to select search engine)
I suspect that clicking search brings another activity that just looks like a quick search. Now I know how to trigger search activity from the quick search but how to intercept quick box call and display your activity instead?
Where would I start with something like that? Any hints and pointers will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can do it easily. see the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/44131089/3649347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no screenshot, I can't help terribly much, since I don't use the official Twitter app (I'm a Seesmic guy), so I don't quite know what you are talking about.

You can override `onSearchRequested()` to get control when the user requests a search in your activity. Return `true` to say you're handling the search yourself. Along the way, pop up whatever you like to allow the user to do a search.

Comment: Here's link to the screenshot http://goo.gl/tdNWy. I'll try to intercept `onSearchRequested` as you suggesting

Comment: @DroidIn.net: Yeah, I would assume they're just intercepting `onSearchRequested()` and handling it themselves.

Comment: Yes - I can intercept search call, so then I will not integrate with Quick Search but instead will call search Activity and dress it up to look like Quick search. Thanks Mark!