# Altering Search Dialog

Tags: android, search

Is it possible to alter the Search Dialog (prior to Android 3.0) on my Activity?  This is the search bar that drops down when you press the hardware search button.  By alter, I mean modify the layout.  I'd like to add an additional button to it if I could.

Comment: The question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150904/android-custom-quick-search-box) looks like what you need. It seems that the way to go is to intercept `onSearchRequested` in your activity and create your own interface.

Comment: You can do it easily. see the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/44131089/3649347

Answer (score 1):

I think floating search box is what you want ~
It's not difficult but its configuration is a little more complicated~
First you need configure parameter of the search bar 
new  a searchable.xml profile like this:

```
<searchable xmlns:android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

　　<!-- label is the text at the bottom of the search bar，hint is the text in the search bar -->
    android:label="@string/search_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" 
    android:searchMode="showSearchLabelAsBadge"

　　<!-- voice search -->
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    android:voiceLanguageModel="free_form"
    android:voicePromptText="@string/search_invoke"


    <!-- Configure search suggestions-->

　　 android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.android.cbin.SearchSuggestionSampleProvider"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ? "
/>
```

you should do this in the mainfest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="SearchResultActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"></action>
</intent-filter>

　　　　　
<!-- searchable.xml -->

<meta-data android:resource="@xml/searchable"

　　　android:name="android.app.searchable"></meta-data>

</activity>
<!-- For each Activity can use search bar,
 be sure to start the label into the Activity 
in which the value is the search results-->
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
     android:value=".SearchResultActivity"
/>

<provider android:name="SearchSuggestionSampleProvider"

android:authorities="com.android.cbin.SearchSuggestionSampleProvider"></provider>
```

then override the onSearchRequested function of Activity

almost like this ，forget the details ~。~！！！

Good luck~